# remove watermark from image, matlab

Tags: image-processing

I have 1000 of images having watermark (text). The position of watermark is random.

I just want to remove it using matlab as manually using (photoshop) is big task.

My question is, what should be work flow.

Any help about literature, link, routines in matlab etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an Image Recovery algorithm and more specifically an [inpainting alogrithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting) would serve your purpose.

Comment: is it effective for 1000 images